# How to make sure Google logout button is available for entire app

Tags: reactjs

I am successfully able to do a Google login. After the successful login routing to next page and getting the sign-out button there.

For that I have created a reusable header component and using it. From that page wanted to route other page with sign out button present in the header component (Actually want to display the sign out button all over the application until the user purposefully signed out).

How can I achieve this?

Created

- Login page
- Google login page imported that to header and using header in all the pages.

login.js

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react';
  import './login.css'
  import { Link,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
  import GoogleLogin from '../login/GoogleLogin.jsx'


function Login(props) {


return (
    <div className="login__container">
          <GoogleLogin className="g-signin" />          
    </div>
   
);
}

export default Login;
```

googleLogin.js

```
   import React, { useState } from 'react';
   import { GoogleLogin, GoogleLogout } from 'react-google-login';
   import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
   const clientId = "Your client ID";

  function Googlelogin(props) {

  const [showloginButton, setShowloginButton] = useState(true);
  const [showlogoutButton, setShowlogoutButton] = useState(false);
  const history = useHistory(); 
   const onLoginSuccess = (res) => {
    console.log('Login Success:', res.profileObj);
    setShowloginButton(false);
    setShowlogoutButton(true); 
    history.push("/pagination");
 };

  const onLoginFailure = (res) => {
    console.log('Login Failed:', res);
};

 const onSignoutSuccess = () => {
    alert("You have been logged out successfully");
    history.push("/");
};
return (
    <div>
           { showloginButton ?
            <GoogleLogin
                clientId={clientId}
                buttonText="Sign In"
                onSuccess={onLoginSuccess}
                onFailure={onLoginFailure}
                cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
                isSignedIn={true}
            /> : null}

        { showlogoutButton ?
            <GoogleLogout
                clientId={clientId}
                buttonText="Sign Out"
                onLogoutSuccess={onSignoutSuccess}
            >
            </GoogleLogout> : null
        }
     
    </div>
  );
 }
 export default Googlelogin;
```

header.js

```
  import React,{useState} from 'react';
  import GoogleLogin from '../login/GoogleLogin.jsx';
  import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
  import './Header.css'
  import { Link,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
  function Header() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleMoreInfo = () =>{
  history.push("/contacts");
  }
  return (
    <div>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center">
   <Link to="/contacts">Contacts</Link>
   <div class="navbar-collapse  w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
    <GoogleLogin />   
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" onClick={handleMoreInfo}>More Info</a>
        </li>     
    </ul> 
  </div>
 </nav>
 </div>
   );
  }
 export default Header;
```

Comment: If you want the same instance to persist across different pages, it'd be a good idea to use a context. Redux works, but is pretty complicated for just exposing some functions. I personally use a basic react context. If you're interested in the plain context, I can provide my firebase context so you can see how it's implemented. :)

Comment: Joel Hager Yes i am intrested.i can look into that

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html